# Showing: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null, when I call user.reload()

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

I am facing this problem when I call the method reload() from FB Auth: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

The authentication system is working fine.

The code below is called after the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method, in another page.

```
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  Future<void> checkEmailVerified() async {
    print(user.emailVerified);
    print(user.uid);
    await user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      print('ok');
      timer.cancel();
      Get.offAll(() => HomePage(), binding: HomeBinding());
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.user.sendEmailVerification();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      user.reload();
      checkEmailVerified();
    });
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
      } else {
        print('User is signed in!');
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Same clicking in the email verifying, the emailVerified variable doesn't change to the true.
The issue appears when the code call the reload() method.

I already searched for all, but I can't get solved this issue.

The login and the signup system is work fine. The user is registered in the FB Authentication console.

I would like the implementing email verify in my app

Regards,